# Installing NetBeans 6.7.1 with JDK 1.6

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, java-6, netbeans6.7

I need to install JDK 1.6.14 in order to install NetBeans 6.7.1.

I uninstalled from control panel JDK 1.8.77 but in cmd for "java -version" i have always 1.8.0.77

How can I uninstall all the version of Java (Control Panel is not enough) or how i can install NetBeans 6.7.1?

I tried with ' netbeans-6.7.1-ml-java-windows.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14" ' in cmd but doesn't work

Comment: check your PATH if you are getting "java -version" -> 1.8.0.77

Comment: I removed it and added 1.6 :(

Comment: may be a restart will help you

Comment: IF Java is uninstalled THEN "Java" command will NOT work. secondly you have uninstalled a JDK, and you are checking JRE version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting Java version as 8 even after uninstalling JDK 8 and installing JDK 6 you need to disable the `java.exe` file of Java 8 version. In order to do that follow the below steps.

1. Go to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\` directory and find out `java.exe`
2. Rename that `java.exe` file to `java_rename.exe`
3. Then install JDK 6 and set the JDK path in Environment Variables. (if it's already installed it's OK).
4. Restart your computer to take effect path settings.
5. Now open terminal/command prompt and type `java -version`. This command will show you Java version as 6.

Hope this will be helpful for you.